# Webaudio gain not silent at 0

Tags: web-audio-api

I am using web audio api buffers to play music and sound effect .WAV files in my video game that runs on html5 and javascript. It is being programmed and tested on Safari for Mojave on a Macbook Pro. I use this to get the instant sound playback, in preference to the delayed sound that results from using the regular audio node.

One issue, when playing back buffered sounds, is that when I have a GainNode between the Source and the Destination, I expect the volume to be full when the gain value is 1 and silent when it is zero. But this isn't the case. For some reason the volume is quieter at 0, but still quite audible. But at -1, it is silent. Shouldn't 0 be silent, whether in linear or in logarithmic scale? Are there circumstances where the gain value range would be something other then 0 to 1? I my particular setting, the range seems to be -1 to +1.

Comment: The good part is you already know how to mute it: with -1. No matter of linear or logarithmic scale. I guess it should be 0 but, according to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode/GainNode), `This parameter is a-rate and it's nominal range is (-∞,+∞)`

Comment: Then to avoid future bugs, is there a way to check programatically exactly which value in a given setting you use for silence? I created a test file using the same coding, and it worked the normal way, silent at 0 but full volume at 1. In the context of the video game, it is silent at -1 but full volume at 1. Does the size of the javascript file determine the silence value for the gain value?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. And I'll glad to see your test file and game code.

Comment: since I don't know how to send attachments here, I'll look for an opportunity to post the file to web and send a link.

Comment: if you go to billygard.com/herman/trysongloop.html, this is my test file that works the normal way (where zero is silent). The slider control adjusts the gainNode.gain.value between 0 and 1. It may have to be restarted a time or two if the music doesn't load in time.

Comment: That example works as I expect. Slider full left gives a slider value of 0, which means the gain value is 0 and  I hear nothing.

Comment: Try this now. in Safari, go to billygard.com/herman/ and push "Click to Play". Game starts with music. Type "debug". in box that appears type ""gainNode.gain.value" and hit return. 1 appears in result. add "=0" to expression. Note music is quieter. Change =0 to =-1. Now it's silent. You may need to enable autoplay for the website.

Comment: So far I can't recreate the error outside the rather complex coding of the video game. Basically I figured the gainNode.gain.value was a value you multiply the the sample value by, in which case a zero value would always be silent. But somewhere this value must be getting altered. I still don't know how gainNode.gain.value=-1 would end up silencing the sound being sent through it. That should produce an inverted (negative) signal, not a zero one.

Comment: I think I may have found the bug. In the doe I saw this: source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(synth.destination);
source.connect(synth.destination); In other words when I conntected the source to the gainNode and the gainNode to the destination. I noticed the statement connecting the source directly to the distination was still there. I deleted it, and I saw the bug seemed to disappear. I may have solved it after all.